# How to send Ajax requests cross-domain?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've had a fit for the past few days trying to figure out how to communicate across domains with ajax requests.

I have this file...

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

?>
<script>
    function send(user){
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://forumchest.com/kb_exchange.php";
        var data = "user="+user;
        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.onload = function(){
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){ 
                var text = hr.responseText;
alert(text);
            } else {
                alert(hr.readyState + " " + hr.status);
            }
        }
        hr.send(data);
    }
</script>
<?php

include_once("conn.php");

$fetch_sites = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sites");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_sites)){
    $site_id = $row['id'];
    $site_address = $row['address'];

    $fetch_subs = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE site='$site_id'");
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_subs)){
        $sub_user = $row1['user'];
        $sub_username = $row1['username'];

        echo "<script>send('$sub_username');</script>";
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

It is attempting to send an ajax request to the following file hosted on a different server with a different domain name.

```
<?php

header("Content-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

?>
<script>
    function respond(user, posts){
        var data = "user="+user+"&posts="+posts;
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        hr.open("POST", "http://xenforotest.esy.es/responder.php", true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.send(data);
    }
</script>
<?php  

$conn = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "db");
if(!$conn){
    echo "this1";
} else {
    echo "this2";
}

$user = $_POST['user'];

$fetch_user = "SELECT message_count FROM xf_user WHERE username='$user'";
$query_user = mysqli_query($conn, $fetch_user);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_user);
    $message_count = $row['message_count'];

echo "<script>respond('$user', '$message_count');</script>";

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

I am getting two responses from the first file saying "2 200" and "3 200". So I'm getting a readyState of 2 and a status of 200.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: You run both of those sites? Because the `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` has to be on the page being called *by* the Ajax, not the page making the request.

Comment: The header command is on both. And yes I own both sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

and not

```
header("Content-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: WOW thank you very much! That solved it! Can't believe the problem was that simple. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain is not relevant there. Your problem is that you send data as a url string.. POST data should be in [formdata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object of javascript

Comment: This same method works every time when I'm sending requests between files on the same server. Suddenly it doesn't work when I try cross-domain.

Comment: see (here)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send()] is states: "Be aware to stop using a plain ArrayBuffer as parameter. This is not part of the XMLHttpRequest specification any longer. Use an ArrayBufferView instead (see compatibility table for version information)." You propobly used GET method before ? Here you use post ..

Comment: Nah I was using post method.

Comment: this is puzzle.. If i get you right, user is ajaxing to server1, and server1, based on userData is ajaxing to server2 ?? What kinda hacking is this ... :D

Comment: LOL well the second file actually ajaxes to a third file that isn't included in the post.